# Changing ImageView depends on Tab

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I am having 2 Tab fragment in an activity.An activity has a circle imageview at the center. While I swipe 1st Fragment,I need to show 1st image & same as for 2nd tab swipe with different image.

[image]   [image]

**UPDATE:**

```
 static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_logo);
                return new LogInFragment();

            case 1:
                imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.add_image);
                return new SignUpFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                return "LOGIN";
            case 1:

                return "SIGNUP";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer, it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    if (i == 0) {
      ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
    }
    else if (i ==1) {
      ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using ViewPager in my app.

Comment: Yes...Now i m using ur edited codes @FabioVenturiPastor

Comment: ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated now. Need to use ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener instead.

Comment: Didnt get @sasikumar... For Both fragment getting same images

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I understand what you want to do:
First delete all the code where you change the image and try this:

```
static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    yourImageView.setImageResource(R.id.yourResource1);
                    fragment = new LogInFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    yourImageView.setImageResource(R.id.yourResource2);
                    fragment = new SignUpFragment();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String str = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    str = "LOGIN";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    str = "SIGNUP"; 
                    break;
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
```

Thats all you need

Comment: Sorry..Getting 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference.

Comment: Show your fragment code please, otherwise if you have 2 diferent fragments why just dont setImageResource on create?

Comment: I am having LogInFragment & SignUpFragment inside of LogInactivity...Image is in LogInActvity.How can I set that image from my fragment.

Comment: LogInActivity.imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.add_image);

Comment: Even I tried it already. And now too I followed you.But only the white circle is shown for both tabs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105542/discussion-between-parama-sudha-and-fabio-venturi-pastor).

Comment: Ya Sure..Please wait for few min

Comment: Probrably returns does not stop the loop, try to add the breaks and tell me if works

Comment: And remember to delete all the code where you change the image except adapter

Comment: Sorry...Didnt get.App is crashed

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference

Comment: try to change:
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainActivityViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
to:
   viewPager.setAdapter(new MainActivityViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

Comment: Thank you so much  @Fabio Venturi Pastor. Got the output.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got it by using the following code by made some modification in @sasikumar answer.

Instead of put **onPageScrollStateChanged** I used to get position in **onPageSelected**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        int i = 0;
        if (position == 0) {
            Log.e("Tab Position", String.valueOf(position));
            imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_logo);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Log.e("Tab Position", String.valueOf(position));
            imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.add_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```